# How can i list all resources across my whole GCP estate that have a specific role?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I can identify all resources with the role Owner in a project by using the following command;

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECTID> --flatten="bindings[].members" --format="table(bindings.members)" --filter="bindings.role:roles/owner"`

To run this command across all projects, I thought this might work but it doesn't...

`for i in $(gcloud projects list | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR>1'); do echo PROJECT: $i && echo "--" && gcloud projects get-iam-policy --project=$i --flatten="bindings[].members" --format="table(bindings.members)" --filter="bindings.role:roles/owner"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your command will list IAM members assigned roles at the project level. In Google Cloud IAM members can also be assigned to resources such as Cloud Storage, KMS, etc. You will need to check every resource in a project/folder/organization. The owner role can also be assigned to resources that are part of another project that is "owned" by someone else. In summary there is no easy way to accomplish your objective.

Comment: @ellefc  As written below, the above script works fine if you just add "; done" at the end. Please edit above to include that, to save the next user much frustration.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out (I didn't close the loop - just needed ;done at the end)

Thought i would share this in case anyone else needs it in the future:

```
for i in $(gcloud projects list | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR>1'); do echo PROJECT: $i && echo "--" && gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i --flatten="bindings[].members" --format="table(bindings.members)" --filter="bindings.role:roles/owner"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. I used the following script that I have from a friend to print all the projects that a certain email or service account has a specific role on.

It does **take a lot of time to execute** but it gets it done, I just tested it.

> for i in $(gcloud projects list | sed 's/|/ /' | awk '{if (NR!=1)
>   print $1}'); do if gcloud projects get-iam-policy "$i"
>   --flatten="bindings[].members" --format="table(bindings.members)" --filter="bindings.role:roles/owner" | grep -q '[USER_OR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT]'; then echo "$i"; fi; done 2> /dev/null

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious, I assume you did replace the parameter with an email or a service account,correct?

I forgot to mention it in my main message. Glad you got it sorted, the one I answered did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use search-all-iam-policies to search all the IAM policies set on folders or projects within your organization.

To find out who has the role Owner:

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/123 --query="policy:roles/owner"
```

To find out whether Amy has the role Owner:

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/123 --query="policy:(roles/owner amy@bar.com)"
```

To find out whether any gmail account has the role Owner:

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/123 --query="policy:(roles/owner *gmail*)"
```

You can change the scope to a folder or a project. You must have the **cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies** permission upon the scope, which is included in the following roles:

- roles/cloudasset.viewer
- roles/cloudasset.owner
- roles/viewer
- roles/editor
- roles/owner

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies

Supported resource types: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types